# I have forgotten my Windows 10 IoT password how can I reset it?

Tags: pi-3, password

How can I recover Windows 10 IoT password for Raspberry Pi 3?

Comment: You can find how to do so at the [Microsoft developer site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/commandlineutils)

Answer (score 4):

I also thought I forgot the password, but I found I never changed it.  The default password is 'p@ssw0rd'.  The key to remember is you have to include the machine name in the username field.  For example... 'minwinpc\Administrator'

To answer the specific question though, I don't believe you can recover the password if you have changed it and forgot it.

Comment: I had set the password in Windows 10 IOT core dashboard when installing the sd card. I didn´t changed the pc name though. It seems it then applies the default password insteadt of the specified.